# ViewPager2 with minheight leaves empty space at the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager2

I have been playing with the [`ViewPager2 with Views`](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/tree/main/ViewPager2#setting-up-viewpager2) sample from Google. I modified the `activity_no_tablayout.xml` to this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:background="#FFFFFF">

    <include layout="@layout/controls" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="250dp" />        <---- added this attribute

</LinearLayout>
```

Technically, I see the ViewPager height set to `250dp` in the layout inspector

[image: Layout-inspector-with-viewPager-height]

Pretty much everything else in the sample is untouched. The adapter content's height is set to `match_parent` and can be found [here](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/blob/main/ViewPager2/app/src/main/res/layout/item_card_layout.xml)

**My goals are:**

1. to have a minimum height set for the contents displayed inside ViewPager
2. all contents must be of same height. That is, if card1 is 300px and card2 is 400px i want the ViewPager height to be 400px
3. If card1 is 100px and card2 is 200px, i want the ViewPager heigh to be 250px (that's the min height from criteria #1)

Comment: try match_parent in the height of viewpager

Comment: If i set the `match_parent`, it'd cover the whole space. I want it to be of certain min_height and expand as the content grows

Comment: with min-height and no content it will have empty space

Comment: Is there someway to fill the viewpager to 250dp? I could set the `layout_height=250dp` but this isn't flexible, right? Like, imagine there is a textview with some large text and the user's phone setting is set to Largest font. In this case, the text would get clipped. I want to avoid this